# Python Thread Acquire Lock Prioritization

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Is there a way to hand over the threading.lock to a pre-decided thread in python. Consider following example:

```
import os, json
import threading
from threading import Lock, Thread
from time import sleep


class Export:

    def __init__(self):
        self.relative_path = "file.txt"
        self.special_lock  = Lock()

    def push(self, data):
        self.special_lock.acquire()
        if not os.path.exists(self.relative_path):
            open(self.relative_path, 'w').close()
        with open(self.relative_path, 'a') as fo:
            json.dump(data, fo)
        self.special_lock.release()

    def rarePrinting(self):
        while(True):
            export.push("Important")
            sleep(1)

    def commonPrinting(self):
        while(True):
            export.push("Not So Important")
            sleep(0.1)

export = Export()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=export.rarePrinting)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=export.commonPrinting)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

t1 is writing some information to the file that is more important then t2, however, since I dont have a graceful exit in my program, I dont know which thread will be blocked on acquire. I just want to guarantee that all of the t1 data that is fetched is written to file, is there a way to prioritize the threads this way without declaring another lock?

Comment: why are you `open`ing the file twice?  also, just writing json encoded objects like that will make it difficult to separate them again when reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a priority queue, which handles locking itself. `rarePrinting` and `commonPrinting` simply put items of different priority into the queue. A third thread takes care of getting the next available item from the queue and adds it to your file.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue


class Export:

    def __init__(self):
        self.relative_path = "file.txt"
        self.jobs = PriorityQueue()

    def writer(self):
        with open(self.relative_path, 'a') as fo:
            while True:
                _, data = self.jobs.get()
                json.dump(data, fo)

    def rare_printing(self):
        while True:
            self.jobs.put((0, "Important"))
            sleep(1)

    def common_printing(self):
        while True:
            self.jobs.put((1, "So Important"))
            sleep(0.1)


export = Export()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=export.rare_printing)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=export.common_printing)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=export.writer)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

All three threads have equal access to the queue, but when `rare_printing` gets the lock, whatever it adds to the queue jumps ahead of anything anything `common_printing` has previously added.

This does assume that `writer` is fast enough to remove jobs faster than they can be added, so that `rare_printing` doesn't starve processing of jobs from `common_printing`.